Laravel Vue js logout got error Uncaught runtime errors:
working with Laravel and Vue js 2 project as well
I have implemented user Authentication system using Laravel and Vue js 2 and laravel passport. my backend using postman is working fine logout as well. I have following AuthController for logout
 public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        auth()->user()->token()->revoke();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Sucessfully Logout']);
    }


and api
  Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
        Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
       });

this is working fine in postman
but in my frontend vue js side I have following logout method in store/index.ts
 logout(context){
      axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer' + context.state.token
      return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        axios.post('/logout').then(res=> {
          localStorage.removeItem('accessToken')
        
        context.commit('removeToken')
        resolve(res.data)
      }).catch(error=> {
        reject(error)
      })
      })
    }

and  logout  link
<li class="nav-item" v-if="loggedIn">
          <router-link class="nav-link"  :to="{name:'Logout'}">Logout</router-link>
        </li>

but when I try to logout following error encounted in the screen
Request failed with status code 401
AxiosError@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/AxiosError.js:23:18
settle@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:24:12
onloadend@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:111:66
and browser inspect console header says
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/logout
401 Unauthorized strict-origin-when-cross-origin
and respond message saya "message   "Unauthenticated."
how could I fix this problem?

It seems you're missing a space between 'Bearer' and the token, which might cause issues with the format of the Authorization header.
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + context.state.token;

Ensure that the token stored in context.state.token is correct and available at the time of the logout request.

now fix my previous error and got following one object is not defined login/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/@vue/vue-loader-v15/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Login.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js:23:30
